# Appending HTML via jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have what seems like a simple problem in my Rails 3.1 app:

I have a series of divs with a class name of 'feed-row':

```
<% @feeds.each do |feed| %>
   <div class="feed-row" data-feedid="<%= feed.id %>">  
   </div>
   <div class="clear">
   </div>
<% end %>
```

The idea is this:

I will gather all of the divs into a collection, loop over each item, pass its data tag to a page that returns an html fragment, then append that fragment into the appropriate div.

The javascript I have to pull the data looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(".feed-row").each(function(){     
        $.get("/retrieve/" + $(this).attr("data-feedid"), function(d) {         
            $(this).append(d);
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Looking at the requests in Chrome's inspector, I can see that the call out going out fine and returning the HTML fragment I intend:

[image]

So, with this HTML fragment, I want to inject it into the *current* row in my loop.

***The Problem Is This***

None of my HTML fragments appear on my page - it is simply missing the data pulled via the jQuery .get() method.

When I inspect the DOM elements, it appears that nothing has been injected inside the elements at all:

```
<div class="feed-row" data-feedid="5"></div>
```

I am sure I am missing something simple here - why is the data I pull down via jQuery never getting to my DOM elements?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: I've seen other problems where modifying an element inside an .each loop doesn't work. Try a short timeout to append the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` in the `$.get` callback is not the same as it is in the `.each()` callback.

```
$(".feed-row").each(function(){    
    var self = this; 
    $.get("/retrieve/" + $(this).attr("data-feedid"), function(d) {         
        $(self).append(d);
    }); 
});
```

What I did was I referenced the element using the `self` variable, then used that variable in the `$.get` callback to reference the element.

So every iteration of `.each()` will have a unique `self` variable, as well as a unique `$.get` callback that references that the unique `self` variable in its scope.

Comment: Knew it would be simple - the context of this makes my head spin sometimes :) Greatly appreciated!